# Hair bones aren't showing up properly in my scene collection

Tags: armature, bones, physics

I just got done with the entire armature. Weight painting etc, everything is rigged and the hair is weight painted properly onto the hair bones I've made for my model.

My issue is that in the scene collection- none of the actual hair bones are selectable. They do not show up under the armature. This makes it so when imported into Unity, I can't select the bones to add physics. They just come up as a solid object.

I'm not really sure how to fix this. This is still the first thing I've made and rigged in Blender so I'm not really sure what to look up either.

[image: Blender Scene Collection]
[image: Unity Hierarchy]

Comment: You have not expanded past the Chest bone. Chances are when you expand it a little further, you will see Chest -> Neck -> Head -> Hair.

Comment: So. You're right and they are there.. perhaps my question is a Unity question, then. Thank you for your help. I guess I was just not looking hard enough haha